# Error with abstract class and methods

Tags: java, arrays, methods, abstract-class

I have an abstract class Player and i want to create two kind of players. Fast and Technical Players.So i created this abtsract class:

```
public abstract class Player
{
    private int speed;
    private int technical;
    private Cell playerCell;

    public abstract void computeAbility();
    public abstract void clonePlayer();

    public Player(){
        Random rand = new Random();
        speed = rand.nextInt(50);
        technical = rand.nextInt(50);
    }

    //i also have accesor and mutator methods
}




  public class FastPlayer extends Player
{
    private int overallAtrributes;

    public FastPlayer(){
        super();
        setSpeed(2*getSpeed());
    }

    public void computeOverallAtrributes(){
                overallAtrributes = getSpeed() + getTechnical();
    }

    public void clonePlayer(){
        FastPlayer cloneFastPlayer = new FastPlayer();
        cloneFastPlayer.setTechnical(getTechnical());
        cloneFastPlayer.setSpeed(getSpeed());
    }
}



public class TechnicalPlayer extends Player
{
    private int overallAtrributes;

    public TechnicalPlayer(){
        setTechnical(2*getTechnical());
    }

    public void computeOverallAtrributes(){
        overallAtrributes = getSpeed() + getTechnical();
    }

    public void clonePlayer(){
        TechnicalPlayer cloneTechnicalPlayer = new TechnicalPlayer();
            cloneTechnicalPlayer.setTechnical(getTechnical());
            cloneTechnicalPlayer.setSpeed(getSpeed());
        }
}
```

Now i want create a reproducePlayer method in Player class to produce a Player of the same type as current Player and i want to put the new person in the same Cell.
So i created this method in Player class:

```
public void reproduce(){
        this.clonePlayer();
        //how can i put the new Player in the same Cell with current Player?
    }
```

I also want to create a method movePlayer which moves the Player in a Random neighbor Cell of my array. i dont have create the class Cell yet.

Comment: What are you doing `public Player()` in `Animal` class? Is it valid constructor for `Animal` class?

Comment: And why is there a `clonePlayer` method that does not even return a value?

Comment: sorry it's not Animal class. its a Player class. i edited my question. Must i return the clonePlayer?

Answer (score 2):

You need to make the clone in the common class.. And than override it or call it.

Something like that:

Under player:

```
public abstract Player clonePlayer();
protected Player clonePlayer(Player newPlayer){
    newPlayer.setTechnical(getTechnical());
    newPlayer.setSpeed(getSpeed());
    return newPlayer;
}
```

Under the player extended classes:

```
Class TechnicalPlayer extends Player
public Player clonePlayer() {
   return super.clonePlayer(new TechnicalPlayer ());
}
```

This should be something like that.. Hope that helps
    }

Comment: can i make it without change the clonePlayer method?

Comment: Yes but it will be wrong.. You can just change all players method return type to player and return the new player you have created.. But this will be need to change in every player type

Comment: if i maκe it with this way i need to make return like:
return (Player) fastPlayer in FastPlayer class and the same for technical class?

Comment: No.. Because The method will return Player.. It will be ok for all of them.. because they all type of player.

Comment: So i only need to return fastPlayer and tecnicalPlayer

Comment: i made the methods to return FastPlayer and TechnicalPlayer. In class Player i wrote this:
`public void reproducePlayer(){
  Player reproducedAnimal = this.clone();
  reproducedAnimal.animalCell = animalCell;
 }`
i want to put the clone player in the same cell with current player. is this true?

Comment: or the second code works better?
public void reproducePlayer(){
  Player reproducedPlayer = new Player();
  reproducedPlayer = this.clonePlayer();
  reproducedAPlayer.setPlayerCell(PlayerCell);
 }

Comment: The first one is wrong and the second one is not logically correct because you create player which is not really and entity.. Why don't you want to go with the way i suggested?

Answer (score 0):

Because all your implementing classes have no-args constructors, you could define just one method on the abstract class that uses reflection to create another instance of the same class as the current one:

```
public Player reproducePlayer() {
    Player p;
    try {
        p = getClass().newInstance();
    catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException ignore) {}
    p.speed = speed;
    p.technical = technical;
    p.playerCell = playerCell;
    return p;
}
```